# How to pass the chosen value in dropdownlist to controller tothen save

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Hey guys please help help how can I pass chosen data in dropdownlist to controller to save then. Here is the code I am using:
The view:

```
 <div class="form-group">
     {{Form::label('IncomeExpense', 'Income&Expense')}}
     {{Form::select('IncomeExpense', array( 'Expense', 'Income'),null,['class'=>'form-control'])}}
    </div>


<div class="form-group">
            {{Form::label('', 'Income')}} 
            {{Form::select('IncomeId', $incomes,null,['class'=>'form-control','id'=>'Income',  'onChange'=>'validate()'])}}
           </div>
```

The controller:

```
 $incexp= new IncomeExpenses();
 $incexp->IncomeExpense=$request->input('IncomeExpense');
 $incexp->save();
```

Model class

```
class IncomeExpenses extends Model
{
    public function income(){
        return $this->hasOne(Income::class);
    }
    public function expense(){
        return $this->hasOne(Expenses::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: What dos your IncomeExpense class look like? Where is it taking in parameters?

Comment: @JoeAlvini, you mean model class if yes then class IncomeExpenses extends Model
{
    public function income(){
        return $this->hasOne(Income::class);
    }
    public function expense(){
        return $this->hasOne(Expenses::class);
    }
}

Comment: Im sorry, I overlooked it. But your right that is the model class. LOL. ALso just edit your answer dont include code in the comment. It is very hard to read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

Try using `$incexp->IncomeExpense=$request->IncomeExpense;` instead of `$request->input('IncomeExpense');`

---

This is just like sending any other form, are you having trouble only with dropdowns ?

Your form open call should look something like this:

```
{!! Form::open(['method' => 'POST',  'url' => url('yourURL')] ) !!}
```

Depending on the version of Laravel 5... you will have to set the routes in the file routes.php or web.php

```
Route::post('yourURL', 'YourController@store');
```

Your store method should be something like

```
/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'yourInput'                 => 'required',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect()->intended('yourURL')->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
    }

    DB::beginTransaction();
    $incexp= new IncomeExpenses();
    $incexp->IncomeExpense=$request->IncomeExpense;
    $incexp->save();

    DB::commit();

    return redirect()->intended('yourURL/' . $incexp->id );
}
```

Comment: thank you for your solution but frankly there are other dropdowns in the view and when I save the form, then again IncomeExpense dropdown doesnot pass the value I select in IncomeExpense dropdown but as a value of IncomeExpense dropdown, there passes the value of Income dropdownlist. Check it out I have edited my question

Comment: again as a value of IncomeExpense dropdownlist, there passes the value of Income dropdownlist

Comment: how are you posting the request? are you using ajax? ... what happens when you 
dd($request)

Comment: yes I am posting {!! Form::open(['action'=>'IncomeExpenseController@store', 'method' =>'POST']) !!}

Comment: Am I doing correctly by using array {{Form::select('IncomeExpense', array( 'Expense', 'Income') in IncomeExpense dropdown maybe array is not recognized properly. What do you think?

Comment: I edited my original answer, also... i really don't remember, but as a standard i always use key => value arrays, not just the values.

Comment: you were right I have used key value pair array and all is perfect thank you dude :). Sorry but don't you know how to show title of foreign key instead of id, that is, now there shows id of INCOME but I need to show title column in INCOME table. If you cannot help ok just ignore this mesage. Thank you again:)

Comment: I could help, only i did not understand the question XD... neither do i know the tables you are refering to, also im falling asleep a bit :'( ... if you post a question, comment the url and if i can i would help you. no worries